# 内匠 (たくみ) 金木 (かねき) - how common are these family names?

Tags: kanji, names

For example, https://myoji-yurai.net says

1500 people with Family Name Takumi([https://myoji-yurai.net/searchResult.htm?myojiKanji=内匠](https://myoji-yurai.net/searchResult.htm?myojiKanji=%E5%86%85%E5%8C%A0))
4600 people with Family name Kaneki ([https://myoji-yurai.net/searchResult.htm?myojiKanji=金木](https://myoji-yurai.net/searchResult.htm?myojiKanji=%E9%87%91%E6%9C%A8))

Is this right? Found it surprising. Does Takumi Sound Weird As A Family Name? I thought Kaneki was a made up anime name.

Comment: You have asked roughly the same question three times over the past week, and each time it’s been closed.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds about right. 1,500-4,500 is not a big number considering the population of Japan (over 100 million). There are famous people with those surnames.

- [金木賢一](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%86%85%E5%8C%A0%E6%94%BF%E5%8D%9A)
- [内匠政博](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%87%91%E6%9C%A8%E8%B3%A2%E4%B8%80)

Note also that that website seems to classify names by their written forms, not pronunciations. Both 内匠 and 金木 can have other readings that are not Takumi and Kaneki. (Conversely, Takumi and Kaneki can be spelled differently.)

Comment: Ahh yes, the other spellings are still pronounced the same sometimes so that would increase the numbers a little bit. Thanks for clarifying :)

Comment: @OliverGardner all of the provided readings for 内匠 and 金木 would sound different, so I don't think that would mean there are more Takumi's and Kaneki's than what you see for the cumulative number. To me it can only mean there are fewer.